# variable undefined Jquery socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a table with the following data.

**description**
object 1
object 2
object 3

I try to get this data from my database via socket.io and put the data into a string variable called Objects. The string Objects will look like this *object1,object2,object3*.

If I try to do alert(objects) the string is undefined.
My HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>SlickGrid example 1: Basic grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/slick.grid.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/examples/examples.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

<script src="/lib/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>

  jQuery(function($){
  var socket = io.connect();

  var objects;
  var temp=[];
  socket.on('load data', function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      temp = data[i];
      objects = objects + "," + temp.description;
    };
    objects = objects.substr(10, objects.length-10);
    objects=$.trim(objects);
  });

  alert(objects);   <== undefined

})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried document ready (see here below) since alert(objects) is executed before the socket.io, but this doesn't help.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert(objects);
});
```

How should I solve this issue?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: People might be more interested in helping you if you marked answers to your previous questions as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). (And you would get +2 points!)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [socket.io debugging tool](http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/) inside of the chrome debugger.

```
$(function(){ // don't pass $ as an argument to this function
  var socket = io.connect(), // what are you connecting to?
     objects,
     temp=[];

  socket.on('load data', function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      temp = data[i];
      objects = objects + "," + temp.description;
    };
    objects = objects.substr(10, objects.length-10);
    objects=$.trim(objects);

    alert(objects); // what is the value of objects here?
  });

  alert(objects); // socket.on is asynchronous so this line is will pretty much always
                  // be executed before your callback function for socket.on()
});
```